# Fast way to load bitmap and make a texture in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I'm trying to make a kind of photo viewer with OpenGL ES in Android.

In my app, basically when I click a button then get entire photo paths list in sdcard, make a bitmap from a photo and set texture as this bitmap then draw it just in simple quads. But this is quite slow and even the GL view freezes when it is working

making texture should work in GLthread so I set Listener and use `queueEvent()`

the code snippets like this:

```
public void setTexture(Context context, final String string) {
Bitmap bitmap = null; 
try {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(string));
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// upload texture by bitmap
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
bitmap.recycle();
}


queueEvent(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   for (int i = 1; i < photos.size() - 1; i++) {
                       try {
                           exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoList.get(i));
                               } catch (IOException e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }
                               String orientation = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                               Log.d(TAG, "photoOrientation: " + orientation);
                               photos.get(i).setOrientation(Integer.parseInt(orientation));
                               photos.get(i).setTexture(mContext, photoList.get(i));
                           }
                       }
                   });
```

When I check the time, the most time consuming work is `decodeStream()` So How can I improve it? Is there any way more efficient way to upload bitmap to texture? or At least How can I avoid freezing GLView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just changed loading part out of the GL Thread. Then it stops freezing.

I also referred to [a good training example](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for efficient bitmap loading

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`  instead of `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`